# Coded UI with selenium - QA_Agent32.exe crashing with error Failed to load page within 500 ms

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I am using Vs2012 with Selenium driver.  I have recently installed VS2013 also, and also re-installed selenium webdriver (downloaded from Visual Studio Gallery link).  Noticed the tests which were running fine earlier in Chrome started giving error.

The browser launched with log-in page, after entering the credentials, the next page load take some time and before the page load completes QTAgent32.exe crashes and the test case fails with error "The agent process was stopped while the test was running.".  When i tried debugging the error, i am seeing the error in selenium driver as below:

```
Selenium.Internal.SeleniumEmulation.Waiter.WaitTimedOutException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233088
Message=Failed to load page within 500 ms
Source=Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium
```

My doubt is Selenium driver is not taking the wait time period set to coded ui playback and always takes only 500ms.

When i create a new project / test case with the same scenario, everything works fine in Chrome.  The problem is with the existing project only. I tried to change many library references, but couldn't get rid of this error.  Please let me know any pointers to resolve the issue.  I am getting the same error in both VS2012 and VS2013.  I tried remove and re-install the selenium driver again, still i am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing WaitforReadyTimeout for Slow Loading Page. use             `Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyTimeout = 100000; //100000ms` this is the max time a test will wait for page to load.